# Update profile using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing project and i want to update user profile using php mysql when i click
on update button it show that there are error in line 17. please help to find the error.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["n"]))
       {
         header("location:error.php");
       }
    if(isset($_POST["s"]))
     {

      $name=$_POST["nm"];
      $lname=$_POST["lnm"];
      $address=$_POST["ad"];
      $u=$_SESSION["un"];

      $query = "SELECT * FROM signup";

      $result=mysqli_query($result,$query) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
      $i=0;
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          $roll[$i]=$row['rollno'];
          $i++;
      }
      $total_elmt=count($roll);
         require_once("vars.php");
$conn=mysqli_connect(host,uname,pass,db) or die(mysqli_connect_error());


         $query="update signup set name='$nm',lname='$lnm',address='$ad' where user_id='$value'";
         $execute=mysqli_query($conn,$query);$r=mysql_affected_rows();
         mysqli_close($conn);
$msg="Your information is submitted successfully";
    }   
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to open the database first to run the select query.

   move this line to the top:

   `$conn=mysqli_connect(host,uname,pass,db) or die(mysqli_connect_error());`
2. you are using `mysqli_query` function wrong. it should be

   `$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_connect_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Now i have updated your code

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["n"]))
       {
         header("location:error.php");
       }
    if(isset($_POST["s"]))
     {

      $name = $_POST["nm"];
      $lname = $_POST["lnm"];
      $address = $_POST["ad"];
      $u = $_SESSION["un"];

$conn = mysqli_connect(host,uname,pass,db) or die(mysqli_connect_error());

      $query = "SELECT * FROM signup";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $i=0;
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          $roll[$i]=$row['rollno'];
          $i++;
      }
      $total_elmt=count($roll);
         require_once("vars.php");    

 $query="update signup set name='$nm',lname='$lnm',address='$ad' where user_id='$value'";
    $execute=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $r=mysql_affected_rows();
    mysqli_close($conn);
    $msg="Your information is submitted successfully";
        }   
        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks ,, i tried the code you updated but it gives me error in while($row... part..